# VBA - Delete row, copy the rest and append down for multiple times and assign counter value to formula of a column in table

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to coding and VBA. Below is the code that i have so far.

The delete > copy > append part work fine for me. But i want to assign a counter value to the formula of a column in the table for each append. 
How to achieve this?

Many thanks for the help!

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHjVM.png)

```
Private Sub Select_Button_Click()

Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table2")

Dim x As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lr As ListRow

    lastrow = tbl.ListRows.Count
    For x = lastrow To 1 Step -1
        Set lr = tbl.ListRows(x)
        If Intersect(lr.Range, tbl.ListColumns("Dept_Group").Range).Value <> Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$F$2").Value Then
            'lr.Range.Select
            lr.Delete
        End If
    Next x

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = tbl.DataBodyRange
    With tbl    
            For i = 1 To 12
                rng.Copy
                rng.Insert Shift:=xlDown
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

            'After pasting i want to assign the counter value i to column "Period" in table with formula like: "=Month($A$2)- i"

            Next i

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe: `Intersect(rng, tbl.ListColumns("Period").Range).Formula = "=Month($A$2) - " & i`

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks for your comment. Your update did what i expected. The other issue would be the performance. For a file with ~3xxxx records and then copying of  ~3xxx rows after delete, it take hours to complete. Any suggestion on improving the speed of the code?

Comment: It's a slow operation. Try disabling screen updating `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` then restore it at the end of the sub.

Comment: @A.S.H Thanks for your suggestion. Actually i tried disabling Application.{ScreenUpdating , DisplayStatusBar, EnableEvents, DisplayPageBreaks Calculation}. But there are no significant improvement. Any suggestion so in replacing the copy and insert operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting a certain number of rows one by one can be slow. You can try the following method, should be faster and achieve the desired outcome.

```
Private Sub Select_Button_Click()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False: Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo Cleanup
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table2")
        .DataBodyRange.AutoFilter 7, "<>" & Sheet1.Range("$F$2").Value2
        .Range.Offset(1).Delete
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        With .DataBodyRange
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 1 To 12
                .Copy
                .Insert Shift:=xlDown
                .Columns(10).Formula = "=Month($A$2)-" & i
            Next
        End With
    End With
Cleanup:
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True: .ScreenUpdating = True: .EnableEvents = True: .CutCopyMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It did speed up the process and achieve the outcome. Though i have to wait for completion for hours due to large record size. Anyways, thanks very much for your help @A.S.H

Comment: @DT- yeah, processing large datasets needs time, ask me :P.  Anyway, glad to help.